# Node.JS - отладка. Debug, inspector, console

Tags: node.js, сервер, отладка, веб-сервер, консоль

Есть видеоурок от Кантора - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COHIRHitRdc&index=18&list=PLsuEohlthXdkRSxJTkmTstWKHgBHsd3Dx

Многое в видеоуроке от 2013 года уже не актуально.
В комментариях советуют вместо supervisor'a - использовать nodemon
Ну ок.
в VS Code через терминал установил:

> npm i -g nodemon

далее:

> nodemon new.js

И далее я получаю бесконечные **GET /json/version** и **GET /json**

Что это вообще такое? Откуда оно лезет, зачем и почему?

[image: GET /json/version]

Также вместо node-inspector'a советуют ставить расширение для хрома:
 **Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM)**. Установил. В терминале VS Code прописываю:

> node --inspect-brk new.js

далее в хроме открываю вкладку с адресом:

> http://localhost:9229/

[image: Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM)]

... и в консоли открывшегося инспектора получаю упомянутые бесконечные **GET /json/version** и **GET /json**

Что я делаю не так? Где я что пропускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Это просто логи запросов. Если у вас отладка работает, значит вы всё делаете правильно.